# When info is pasted into Cell 'J3' A time stamp is placed in 'AA1', and A time stamp is placed in the next empty cell of column 'AI'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm trying to make a script that when info is pasted into Cell 'J3' it will make a time stamp in cell 'AA1' and additionally it will also make a time stamp in column 'AI' in the first cell that doesn't already have a time stamp.

This would be so the sheet makes a time stamp that gets overridden each time that info is pasted into the sheet, but also make a static time stamp separately of each time info is pasted into the sheet.

I have a script that makes the timestamp that only updates when info is pasted into 'J3'
function:

```
onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 10 && e.range.rowStart == 3 && !e.value) {
    sh.getRange("AA1").setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

I also have a script that takes info from one tab and copies it over to another tab on the first available row.

```
function Delete() {
  
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Testing'), true);
    jumpToFirstEmptyBasic()
  spreadsheet.getRange('Live Data!S2:AE1001').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Live Data'), true);
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2:M1001').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('Live Data!A2')

};
function jumpToFirstEmptyBasic() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Testing"); // << Change the sheet name to your own sheet.
  
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log(lastRow);
  
  sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1).activate();
};
```

Over all, I'm trying to add some of the seconds code to the first so that it has a second function of making a list of time stamps on the same tab whenever info is pasted into the 'J3' cell.
So far this is what I have put together, but it doesn't work, and I'm not experienced enough with python to find out why:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 10 && e.range.rowStart == 3 && !e.value) {
    sh.getRange("AA1").setValue(new Date());
      jumpToFirstEmptyBasic()
    sh.getRange(lastRow).setValue(new Date());
  }
function jumpToFirstEmptyBasic() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  Logger.log(lastRow);
  
  ss.getRange(lastRow+1,1).activate();
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 10 && e.range.rowStart == 3) {
    e.source.toast("Gate1");
    let lr = Number(getColumnHeight(27, sh, e.source));
    sh.getRange(Number(lr) + 1, 27).setValue(new Date());
    sh.getRange("AA1").setValue(new Date();)
    e.source.toast(`The are ${Number(lr) + 1} timestamps on this page.`);
  }
}

function getColumnHeight(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()){ rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
  //const h = Utilities.formatString('col: %s len: %s', col, rcA.length - s);
  //Logger.log(h);
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(h).setWidth(150).setHeight(100), 'Col Length')
}
```

This may also work for you.  But I find it unreliable at times and I'm not sure why.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 10 && e.range.rowStart == 3) {
    e.source.toast("Gate1");
    let lr = Number(sh.getRange("AA1").getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getHeight());
    sh.getRange(Number(lr) + 1, 27).setValue(new Date());
    sh.getRange("AA1").setValue(new Date());
    e.source.toast(`The are ${Number(lr) + 1} timestamps on this page.`);
  }
}
```

But if it works for you it will relieve you of using the helper function getColumnHeight();

Comment: Hello again Cooper, when I'm testing this formula, the second time stamp is just updating itself when new info is pasted to 'J3'. It isn't putting the new time stamp on the next line down. BTW, I really appreciate you helping out with this, you rock

Comment: This time when I used it, the first time stamp isn't updating(the one that is supposed to override the prior time stamp in AA1) instead, It's making a time stamp a few rows below in column 'AA', and a second time stamp that is in column 'A'. When I run it multiple times, it skips several lines down from each time stamp, and makes new ones. Can you make it so the 'AA1' time stamp doesn't move, it just overwrites the last time stamp in 'AA1', and the other time stamp that does move, only goes down to the next row instead of skipping down several rows?

Comment: That is just about perfect, but the 'AA1' time stamp isn't updating.

Comment: When is it supposed to update

Comment: That's perfect, thanks Cooper, you are a Rockstar!!!